# What ways can Maven be used to introduce a "shim" to a build that supports two different versions of a dependency?

Tags: java, maven, build, backwards-compatibility, shim

I have a project that I build using Maven, which has a number of different dependencies. A requirement of my project is to build against two different versions of one of these dependencies, using a profile to toggle using one version over the other:

```
<profile>
    <id>use-old-version</id>
    <properties>
        <my.dependency.version>1.0-old-version</my.dependency.version>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

This works just fine, except that there is a difference in the API provided by these versions. It's only a small difference, and is totally manageable by introducing a small "shim" class to delegate which call to use, which gets decided at build time.

How I am currently envisioning solving this problem is by using separate modules for each version's shim class, and declaring this dependency on the older version's shim module in the profile definition.

My question is - is this the best way to do this? What other options would I have for doing such an operation with Maven?

Comment: Profiles as not good. If you have already a "shim" class which handles this than the shim class into a separate module and your usual lib into an other. So a user can decide to use the shim package which has the other version within it and other users can decide to sue directpy the lib module without the shim module.